# How to make react native paper theme snackbar sticky in scroll view at bottom of screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-paper

I want a sticky snack bar from the react-native paper theme. Currently with scroll up the snack bar goes upside as well. Instead, I want to make it fixed at a position in scroll view.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do so is to place the `snackbar` outside the `scrollview`.

Here is an example;

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, Dimensions, View } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Snackbar } from 'react-native-paper';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);

  const onToggleSnackBar = () => setVisible(!visible);

  const onDismissSnackBar = () => setVisible(false);

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>

 
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>

            <Button onPress={onToggleSnackBar}>{visible ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}</Button>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>sjdfsjhfsdjkfhsdkfh</Text>
      <Text>last</Text>
    </ScrollView>
    
         <Snackbar
        visible={visible}
        onDismiss={onDismissSnackBar}
        action={{
          label: 'Undo',
          onPress: () => {
            // Do something
          },
        }}>
        Hey there! I'm a Snackbar.
      </Snackbar>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
});

export default MyComponent;
```

[Link](https://snack.expo.dev/@irfanwani/snackbar?name=Snackbar&description=https%3A%2F%2Fcallstack.github.io%2Freact-native-paper%2Fsnackbar.html&code=import%20*%20as%20React%20from%20%27react%27%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20View%2C%20StyleSheet%20%7D%20from%20%27react-native%27%3B%0Aimport%20%7B%20Button%2C%20Snackbar%20%7D%20from%20%27react-native-paper%27%3B%0A%0Aconst%20MyComponent%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20%5Bvisible%2C%20setVisible%5D%20%3D%20React.useState(false)%3B%0A%0A%20%20const%20onToggleSnackBar%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20setVisible(!visible)%3B%0A%0A%20%20const%20onDismissSnackBar%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20setVisible(false)%3B%0A%0A%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%3CView%20style%3D%7Bstyles.container%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CButton%20onPress%3D%7BonToggleSnackBar%7D%3E%7Bvisible%20%3F%20%27Hide%27%20%3A%20%27Show%27%7D%3C%2FButton%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CSnackbar%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20visible%3D%7Bvisible%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onDismiss%3D%7BonDismissSnackBar%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20action%3D%7B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3A%20%27Undo%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20onPress%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Do%20something%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%7D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Hey%20there!%20I%27m%20a%20Snackbar.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FSnackbar%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FView%3E%0A%20%20)%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20styles%20%3D%20StyleSheet.create(%7B%0A%20%20container%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20flex%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20justifyContent%3A%20%27space-between%27%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aexport%20default%20MyComponent%3B&dependencies=react-native-paper) to the snack.

Extra text is just for scrollview.